# How do I tell ddply to ignore the hms and only look at the ymd?

Tags: r, plyr

The question is about the `ddply` function from the `plyr` package.

I have dates formatted as `2021-10-03 11:15:00`, `2021-10-03 08:15:00`,`2021-10-02 11:15:00`, etcetera.

I formatted it with: `df %>% mutate(Timestamp = ymd_hms(Timestamp))`.

The column Timestamp is part of a larger data frame (df) where I would like to count the number of unique users per day. To do so, I want to make use of the `ddply`
function:

`df_users_per_day <- ddply(df,~Timestamp,summarise,statements=length(unique(User)))`

The current line of code is unable to see that the first two dates belong to the same day. It counts them separately. How do I tell ddply to ignore the hms and only look at the ymd?

Comment: For ddply the timestamp is effectively just a number and those are different. You'll need to turn the timestamp into a date by conversion or truncation somewhere (like an extra column)

Comment: If you're using mutate, why are you using ddply?

Comment: Op is probably using `plyr::mutate`

Comment: Robin is correct. I make use of plyr::mutate. I understand your comment. Conversion or truncation is the better solution.